# Can I do the following fast in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have three matrices in Matlab, A which is n x m, B which is p x m and C which is r x n.

Say we initialize some matrices using:

```
    A = rand(3,4);
    B = rand(2,3);
    C = rand(5,4);
```

The following two are equivalent:

```
 >> s=0; 
 >> for i=1:3 
        for j=1:4 
            s = s + A(i,j)*B(:,i)*C(:,j)'; 
        end; 
    end
 >> s

 s = 

2.6823    2.2440    3.5056    2.0856    2.1551
2.0656    1.7310    2.6550    1.5767    1.6457


>> B*A*C'

ans =

2.6823    2.2440    3.5056    2.0856    2.1551
2.0656    1.7310    2.6550    1.5767    1.6457
```

The latter being much more efficient.

I can't find any efficient version for the following variant of the loop:

```
 s=0; 
 for i=1:3 
      for j=1:4 
           x = A(i,j)*B(:,i)*C(:,j)'; 
           s = s + x/sum(sum(x)); 
      end; 
 end
```

Here, the matrices being added are normalized by the sum of their values after each step.

Any ideas how to make this efficient like the matrix multiplication above? I thought maybe accumarray could help, but not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it efficiently with `bsxfun`:

```
aux1 = bsxfun(@times, permute(B,[1 3 2]), permute(C,[3 1 4 2]));
aux2 = sum(sum(aux1,1),2);
s = sum(sum(bsxfun(@rdivide, aux1, aux2),3),4);
```

Note that, because of the normalization, the result is independent of `A`, assuming it doesn't contain any zero entries (if it does the result is undefined).